# How to omit properties from functions

Tags: typescript

How would one omit a property from a function:

```js
type OmitError = Omit<{
    <T>(result: T): void
    (...results: any[]): void;
    error(...errors: any[]): void;
},'error'> 
// returns {} but should return
// {
//   <T>(result: T): void 
//   (...results: any[]): void; 
// }
```

Comment: You can't do this programmatically in any usable way, unfortunately.  Mapped types drop call signatures.  If you had a single non-generic call signature I could imagine writing a utility type for it, but nothing's going to work well with generics & overloads.  What's the use case?

Comment: Right now all I can do is write up an answer that says that this is not possible, along with links to GitHub issues as sources.  If you're looking for some kind of workaround, that would depend on the use case.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected - as I saw a type `JustSignatures` - which doesn't cover a number of edge cases.  The use case, was me expanding my type toolbox to have an `Omit` that works as one would expect it to work.  As I often use functions with properties.

Comment: @jcalz - thanks, I trust what you are saying, and can search Github myself - so no need.

Comment: Well, either I write up an answer saying "no, sorry", or you [edit] the question that demonstrates an actual use case... when you say "I often use functions with properties", that's what I want to know more about. What functions with properties are you using where you need to `Omit` from them? Are you putting those properties on those functions yourself?  If so, then you have the types to start with, and you can just use them.  Or are those functions-with-properties coming from some external source and you actually *need* to probe them with type manipulating functions?

Comment: @jcalz Generally I prefer to use functions over plain objects - as they enable `fn(whatever)` without forcing redundant method calls e.g. `obj.doX(whatever)`.   Typically I add properties via `Object.defineProperties`.  Because I prefer functions, I'd like `Omit` and in fact all of the other utilities to work with them by default.